# Using Artifactory Java client with API Key?

Tags: java, artifactory

I can't find an example **anywhere** of how to upload to Artifactory using the java client and API key (not username/password). Can anyone help me? All I have so far is:

```
Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClientBuilder.create()
            .setUrl("https://artifactory.company.com")
            .build();
```

I think I need to use `ArtifactoryRequest` somehow, but I don't know how to use them both together...

Comment: Maybe `setAccessToken`?

Comment: It's not an access token. It's an API Key. To my understanding, they're not the same. The API Key has to be set with a header.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation, it seems that only username/password is supported https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java/blob/master/README.md

Looking at the source code, it seems that only username/password and accessToken are supported https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java/blob/master/services/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/artifactory/client/ArtifactoryClientBuilder.java

There are a few feature requests about this (https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java/pull/103), but there seems to be a workaround where manually setting the 'X-JFrog-Art-Api' should do the trick. This would involve fiddling manually with the headers.

Personally, I have always used the fact that the API key may be used as a replacement for the password in the 'Authentication' field.

More information about credentials at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Example-DeployinganArtifact

Can you try the following, using the API Key as a password.

Note that you also need the username attached to the API Key

```
Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClientBuilder.create()
.setUrl("ArtifactoryUrl")
.setUsername("username")
.setPassword("APIKEY")
.build();
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Hi, sending apiKey as password doesn't work. Seems like `X-JFrog-Art-Api` is not supported at java client

Answer (score 0):

```
    Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClientBuilder.create()
    .setUrl("ArtifactoryUrl")
    .setAccessToken([your access token])
    .build();
```

works like a charm..
to create an access token try to use this command:

```
curl -uadmin:[PASSWORD] -XPOST "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/security/token" -d "username=[USERNAME]" -d "scope=member-of-groups:readers"
```

Answer (score 0):

jfrog java client does not support apiKey. But you can create your own http interceptor and add apiKey to headers.

This is a custom interceptor:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.protocol.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyHttpProcessor implements HttpProcessor {
    private final String apiKey;

    public MyHttpProcessor(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
        httpRequest.addHeader("X-JFrog-Art-Api", apiKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
    }
}
```

You can pass the interceptor to the builder as below:

```
org.jfrog.artifactory.client.Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClientBuilder.create()
                .setHttpProcessor(new MyHttpProcessor(apiKey))
                .setUrl(baseUrl)
                .build();
```